# Is it common/ok to declare global class instances in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I recently watched a [video tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/Swift-tutorials/Building-Note-Taking-App-iOS-9-Swift/376981-2.html) in Lynda.com and I noticed that the author declared a few global variables which included two class instances. The main reason for my question is because I have heard that we need to try to avoid using global variables unless your really need them. I can see using global variables for `NSUserDefaults' Keys` but I'm not sure about global instances.

Here is the code showing the global variables declarations. I'm only concerned about variables `masterView` and `detailViewController`.

```
import UIKit

var objects:[String] = [String]()
var currentIndex:Int = 0

var masterView:MasterViewController?
var detailViewController:DetailViewController?

let kNotes:String = "notes"
let BLANK_NOTE:String = "(New Note)"

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

     // class code 

}
```

Is it ok to declare your class instances as global variables?

Comment: I haven't seen the video, but possibly this is only used for the sake of learning (i.e., in a Playground)? In a Playground, all variables that are not part of a closure (class, struct, function) are, per se, "Playground global". Generally, we want to avoid global variables (as you say), including class instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly OK to use global variables in your Swift code from the technical point of view, in the sense that your program is not going to crash or otherwise "misbehave" because of that. When you are building a quick example for a demonstration, global variables provide a convenient way to shorten the code.

However, there are drawbacks to using mutable global variables that makes their use questionable. Specifically, they break encapsulation. Looking at the code that you provided, two variables

```
var objects:[String] = [String]()
var currentIndex:Int = 0
```

should be hidden in a model object, over which you have some degree of control.

Using globals may produce some unexpected behavior if you are not careful about clearing them. For example

```
var masterView:MasterViewController?
var detailViewController:DetailViewController?
```

may retain references to view controllers that are no longer visible.

Comment: I do understand that for quick demonstrations it would make your code cleaner but I'm not sure if showing bad practices is a good idea since this tutorial is about creating a `Notes App` and the main reason I watched it is to see how code should be structured in a real application. As you I also noticed the mutable variables he added which I know could cause problems but I wasn't sure if global instances was common. Do you know of any tutorial where an app is created following good programming patterns?

Comment: @fs_tigre I agree, demos should strive to use best practices wherever it is practical. Making a demo on structuring your app, on the other hand, would be quite hard, because too many parts are required. I don't know of any such demo or tutorial. The most useful reading for me on the subject of high-level structuring my app was Apple's [MVC discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14).

Answer (score 2):

That's okay to declare a class instances as a global variable, if you want to prefer use of only one instance of that class through out your app work.
**NOTE:** you can hide those properties & functions of that instance by making those ***Private***, which you don't want to be accessed by global instance variable.